# can there be a tooltip with data from the database

Tags: yii, tooltip, json

I need to know can there be a tooltip populated with data from database to be displayed in the tooltip.

something like the tooltip should contain

```
   name    stauts
   abc     active
   xyz     active
   pqr     active
```

name and status are retrived from db

I need this tooltip onmouseover, am  using  CJSON decoded to render the content

i did go google but hardly did find that i would throughly understand and implement.

can anyone out there has any ideas for what am looking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a extension named [yii-bootstrap](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-bootstrap/), which described clearly [here](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/).

For using tooltip easily in this extension, just look [here](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbTooltip).

Comment: sorry for the late reply as i had fever know am well.thanks am yet not sure how should i carry on it l give it a try.

Comment: Ok. It is so easy, try it certainly. It is just an extension.

Comment: ya have used bootstrap for buutons l try and let u know

Answer (score 0):

I use cluetip for this. Its not related to Yii but will give you some idea :

**JS**

```
function renderInfoTips(opts){
    var elements=$('#'+opts.form).get(0).elements;
    for(i=0; i<opts.tips.length;i++){
        $(elements[opts.tips[i].field]).parent().prepend(opts.tips[i].tip);
    }

    var clue_opts={arrows:true,splitTitle: '|',closePosition: 'title',sticky:true,dropShadow:false,mouseOutClose:true,
            onShow:function(ct, ci){
                if(!$.browser.webkit) $(ct).css('top',$(ct).position().top- 30+'px');
            }
        }

    $('#'+opts.form).find(".infotip").cluetip(clue_opts);
}
```

**PHP**

```
function setInfoTipsJavascript($form_id,infotips){
        if (count($this->infotips) <1 ) return '';
        //get all tip names
        $names_csv=join(',',array_keys(infotips));

        //get tips details from db
        $query="select name, description from infotips where FIND_IN_SET(name ,'$names_csv')";
        //run the query, in Yii you have to use InfoTipsModel , I have skipped that portion
            //$infotipS , lets say this is query object 
        $tips=array();
        while($tip=$infotipS->Assoc()){
            $this->infotips[$tip['name']]['tip']="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='infotip' title='|{$tip['description']}'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
            $tips[]=$this->infotips[$tip['name']];
        }

        $tips=json_encode($tips);

        $script="\nrenderInfoTips({\"form\":'{$form_id}', \"tips\":{$tips}});\n\n";

        echo $script;
    }
```

I am sharing this hoping this will give u some idea. Its obvious you have to : create infotips table, a model for that, and create a widget etc to fetch infotips related to your form fields . As someone suggested, if you are using Bootstrap, you have better way to do that.

Comment: can u pls explain the JS am not getting it .is it that you are u MVC using.and why do have i to : create infotips table. the thing is am having table,model the query should render the the output to the tooltip .and about creating the widget ... am not having idea as to how to create widget in yii .. can you please elaborate things